# Return data filtered on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular5

In my component.ts I have a function that returns data from a service, and saves it to myPosts object. The function is called getData();
What I want to do is filter getData initially by date before calling it on ngOnInit().

So initially my table would display all last months' posts. 
And then I should be able to change the date on another function and filter for different ranges.

My filtering functions are on the controller.
How do I call the filter Function after I get the data, so that initially that data is filtered on ngOnInit ?

```
public getData() {
this.postsService.getAllPosts().subscribe(results => {
  this.myPosts= results['data'];    
});
}

filterByDate(){
  const monthAgo= moment().subtract(1, 'month');
   this.myPosts= this.myPosts.filter(item => moment(item.SubmittedDate).isAfter(monthAgo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to filter and then assign the data as below,

```
filterByDate(myPosts){
  const monthAgo= moment().subtract(1, 'month');
   return myPosts.filter(item => moment(item.SubmittedDate).isAfter(monthAgo));
}
```

In your onInit function, use that function

```
public getData() {
this.postsService.getAllPosts().subscribe(results => {
  this.myPosts= this.filterByDate(results['data']);    
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But where do I call this so that this data is the one that gets returned initially ? 
currently on ngOnInit I call the getData();

Comment: MyPosts will have filtered results, yes. But Then if the user changes the range of dates to be shown ?
I call filterByDate on ngModelChange and I dont give myPosts as input.
I guess I'll have to use two separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `getData()` method in the constructor and then use the filter function `filterByDate()` in ngOnInIt

```
export class SomeClass implements OnInIt {
      public getData() {
        this.postsService.getAllPosts().subscribe(results => {
          this.myPosts = this.filterByDate(results['data']);
        });            
      }
      public filterByDate(myPosts){
          const monthAgo = moment().subtract(1, 'month');
          return myPosts.filter(item =>  
          moment(item.SubmittedDate).isAfter(monthAgo));
        }
      constructor() {
        this.posts = this.getData();
      }
      ngOnInIt() {
        this.filterPosts = this.filterByDate(posts);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is it a must to give myPosts as an input parameter to the function?They're declared in the controller. 
the issue is that I have filterByDate(startDate,endDate,lastMonth) which is called on ngModelChange..
And if lastmonth==true, then I filter for last month.
Because I want to be able to use the same function when user chooses a range of date to filter from.
But I was having issues to have the initial result to already be filtered for last month.